# Java and Windows Look & feel

Tags: java, swing, windows-xp, look-and-feel

I made a swing application that scans Images; and each Image represented by a leaf I a tree

the problem that I faced is that it throws this exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.XPStyle$Skin.getWidth(XPStyle.java:513)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.XPStyle$Skin.getWidth(XPStyle.java:517)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsTreeUI$ExpandedIcon.getIconWidth(WindowsTreeUI.java:138)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.drawCentered(BasicTreeUI.java:1580)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.paintExpandControl(BasicTreeUI.java:1464)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.paint(BasicTreeUI.java:1206)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:143)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:763)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1027)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5122)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:285)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1128)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5070)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4880)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:723)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:679)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:659)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:128)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

and I don't know why this appears
Note: I am using Windows Look and feel

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
```

and java 1.6_22
under windows-7

Comment: Can you post your code please? It's hard to tell what's going on without the code.

Comment: can you post the source code?

Comment: I do not believe the problem is with the library itself. Do you mind sharing how you are scanning for images in directory. I sense problem with input. ( list of images in dir)

Comment: Actually, I could well believe this is a problem with the Windows PL&F. A minimal example of code that triggers the problem would be good. Possibly it is quite machine specific.

Comment: UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");  // Bad, *Bad,* **Bad** UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()); // good, *good,* **good** - Your version will not work on anything but Windows, not that Mac and Unix users would want to see Windows PLAF on their desk-top in any case.  As to the suggestion to 'post code' - I 'downvote' that.  Instead post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  Also, my WAG is that the code is doing something *off* the EDT, that should be done **on the EDT.**

Comment: Just use SWT... the Swing implementation on Windows 7 sucks anyway.

Comment: Did you set the look and feel before or after the component's frame was visible? I vaguely remember getting this nullpoiner when changing the look and feel to WindowsLookAndFeel if a frame was already visible.

Comment: @Lucass PLAF can be changed when a JFrame (or JApplet) is already visible.  It is just necessary to call SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(Component) to ensure the tree of components is adjusted.

Comment: I used UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName() first but still problem found. and also it is the first line in my main()method

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this:

```
//Set the look and feel to users OS LaF.
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: "//Set the look and feel to windows."  No it does not do that.  At least, not on a Mac. or *nix OS.

Comment: Oh my god I love it. On windows this looks AWESOME.

Comment: Please consider voting the answer up if it helped you.

Comment: Why not `catch (Exception e)`?

Comment: WChargin: the try catch blocks were probably generated individually by the IDE (eclipse behaves like this).